# Are there any code example(s) of how to make video cards invisible?

Tags: video-streaming, kernel, pci-bus

Are there any code example(s) of how to make video cards invisible? As per my understanding this should be done on kernel level. What I'm trying to do is the folliowing - I have four physical GPUs using PCI-Express x8/x8/x8/x8.  I can have two physical cards in configuration of x16/x16 instead.  What I want to do is programmatically switch the configuration of four cards to two cards and back to use x8 to x16 back to x8 mode.  Greatly appreciate for your help.

Roman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be dependent on your video card driver. You'd have to ask the manufacturer of your specific video card for an API or functionality in their driver that supports this; it's not a normal part of Windows or the Linux kernel either, AFAIK.